# Confusion with regard to rendering of children/props - when are expression evaluated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have progress bar component and a component which uses it:

```
const Progress = ({children, show}) => {
  if (!show) return <ProgressBar />;
  return children;
}

const ComponentUsingProgress = () => {
  const {loaded, data} = loadData();

  return <Progress show={!loaded} >
          <div someProp={data.nested1.nested2} />
         </Progress>
}
```

Even though the progress bar only ever renders children when the data is loaded, this throws an error related to accessing undefined properties on the data object. I would not expect the error because I thought the progress bar would only ever render children once the data is loaded. What gives?

Comment: Need more details on the error

Comment: May be you are expecting something like React Suspense hooks which i am not sure though

Comment: The error will be something like: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nested2' of undefined

Comment: can you console the data or what does loadData() return?

Comment: loadData might return something like {loaded: true, data:{ nested1: {nested2: 'foo'}}}. I figured that because the progress bar only renders children when data is loaded, that the child (<div someProp={data.nested1.nested2} />) would only ever be evaluated when the data was loaded, but it appears that is incorrect.

Comment: "loaded?(<ProgressBar />):(<div someProp={data.nested1.nested2} />)" does this code work fine?

Comment: Yes it does. That is what I have had to resort to - not making the components with the data dep children of the progress bar, but rather returning the progress bar outright. I would like to understand what is happening under the hood and why the original snippet results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody with similar confusion, I think I found the answer in (of all places) the react docs:

> Babel compiles JSX down to React.createElement() calls.

From what I understand this compilation step takes place when the parent is invoked. React.createElement is called on children, causing props to be evaluated (even though they may not be rendered).